# Fix subscript and superscrtpt position by command

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts

I have been using the following `\subsup` command

```
\newcommand{\subsup}{
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\check@mathfonts
\fontdimen16\textfont2=2.5pt
\fontdimen17\textfont2=2.5pt
\fontdimen14\textfont2=4.5pt
\fontdimen13\textfont2=4.5pt}
\makeatother}
```

in order to change the default positions of subscripts and superscripts in math mode. I used the `\subsup` command when needed and I was compiling with MikTex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\newcommand{\subsup}{
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\check@mathfonts
\fontdimen16\textfont2=2.5pt
\fontdimen17\textfont2=2.5pt
\fontdimen14\textfont2=4.5pt
\fontdimen13\textfont2=4.5pt}
\makeatother}

\subsup
\begin{document}
\[ x_A \]
\end{document}
```

When I switched to TexLive I got the following errors

`Package amsmath Error: \check allowed only in math mode. \begin{document}
Font \nullfont has only 7 fontdimen parameters. \begin{document}`

In order to fix that I had to call the same code without the `\subsup` command, just placed right before `\begin{document}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\check@mathfonts
\fontdimen16\textfont2=2.5pt
\fontdimen17\textfont2=2.5pt
\fontdimen14\textfont2=4.5pt
\fontdimen13\textfont2=4.5pt}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[ x_A \]
\end{document}
```

Is there another simple way to use this code by command?

Comment: Please give us a complete example that shows how you're using the command.

Comment: any differences in tex errors will be due to using different latex release or different packages, not due to using texlive rather than miktex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the catcode change in the wrong place, `\makeatletter` does nothing here

```
\newcommand{\subsup}{
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\check@mathfonts
\fontdimen16\textfont2=2.5pt
\fontdimen17\textfont2=2.5pt
\fontdimen14\textfont2=4.5pt
\fontdimen13\textfont2=4.5pt}
\makeatother}
```

you want

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subsup}{
\AtBeginDocument{
\check@mathfonts
\fontdimen16\textfont2=2.5pt
\fontdimen17\textfont2=2.5pt
\fontdimen14\textfont2=4.5pt
\fontdimen13\textfont2=4.5pt}
}
\makeatother
```